# SQL ID dependent on android device

Tags: android, sql, android-database

I'm creating android app in which user store some data. I want to add an option that two users can synchronize/merge their databases. I want to do this by checking if an ID of element from one database exists in second one. This disclaims using simple `INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT` cause in both databases there will be element with ID e.g. `1` which won't mean that those elements are the same. I was thinking about an ID that has some prefix that is unique for every android device and then some number e.g. `ABCD000001` where `ABCD` is this unique device ID. But the problem is I don't know how to generate this prefix. Do you have any ideas? Also maybe you have better idea than checking ID...

Comment: Try adding a prefix with unique identifier. Look at this page: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a prefix using device `IMEI` but you will need `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. Also you can use `android-id` but it can be null or not unique for some devices. 
So I strongly suggest to use [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626208/3341752)  to create a `uuid` that is unique for each device. I have used it and it works fine on different devices.